# File systems in C in linux

Tags: c, linux, io, posix

I am writing codes in c using linux and trying to read from a file. I have already run the code and it works perfectly but i am trying to understand the logic behind using the file descriptor and the buffer including the parameters. Please help from line r=read(fd,buff,1);

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void main()
{
 int fd,r;
 char buff[100];
 fd=open("test.dat",O_RDONLY);
 if (fd==-1)
 {
    printf("Failed to open and read the file test.dat\n");
    exit(1);
 }
    r=read(fd,buff,1);

    while (r>0)
    {
        printf("%s",buff);
        r=read(fd,buff,1);

    }

close (fd);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works perfectly? Cause if you don't set `buff[1] = 0`, the good behavior is not guaranteed

Comment: FYI, this question has very little to do with file systems and isn't Linux specific at all

Comment: r is the number of bytes read

Comment: @MadPhysicist, yeah it works. I've run it

Comment: @geckos can you be more specific?

Comment: `read` return the number of bytes read. The while loop read on character at time, the number of bytes read is returned, when is 0 the while stops

Comment: @geckos, yeah and what does the '1' mean in read(fd,buff,1)?

Comment: [The third parameter to `read` is the number of bytes requested.](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) You can get that information in Unix, including Linux, by displaying the manual page for `read` using the command `man read`.

Comment: Please quote from the specification of `read()` the part you have trouble understanding. In which way does it fail to explain to you the meaning and use of the third parameter?

Comment: Check the manual https://linux.die.net/man/2/read

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `read` returns number of bytes read. In your code, you are reading 1 byte each time and printing it. So, when it reaches end of file, it will stop (as `read` will return 0).

You can read more bytes in one `read`. In this case, `read` can return two values (if `read` succeeded, of course):

1. Number of bytes read, that you requested (`read(fd, buff, 12)` will return 12)
2. If there is fewer bytes to read than you requested (let's say you requested 100, but file consists of 40 characters), it will return number of bytes it read from file, not the one you requested (i.e. it will return 40, instead of 100).

Comment: yeah u r right. But what happens when read comes across a string terminating character each line ('\0')?

Comment: Well, `\0` is non-printable character, so you cannot see or write that character into the file. Moreover, at the end of the each line, there is `\n` character, not `\0`. Even, if you read data, more than one line, `\n` will be inside of your string. So, after reading, you buffer can contain: "Hello World\nNew Line"